# Find the directional derivative of $ f = (f_1, f_2) $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find the derivative at the origin $(0,0)$, and with respect to the unit vector $ u = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) $ of the following function $ f = (f_1, f_2) $, whose components are the functions $ f_1: \Bbb R ^ 2 \to \Bbb R $ and $ f_2: \Bbb R ^ 2 \to \Bbb R $ defined by the expressions,
$$\begin{cases}
f_1(x,y)=\dfrac{\sin x^2-\sin y^2}{x-y}, x\ne y; & \text{ } f_1(x,x)=0 \\ 
f_2(x,y)=\dfrac{\ln(x^2+y^2+1)}{x-y},x\ne y; & \text{  } f_2(x,x)=0 
\end{cases}$$

We know that the directional derivative is defined as, $$f'(a,u)=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f(a+tu)-f(a)}{t}$$ First of all, notice that $f((0,0))=(f_1(0,0),f_2(0,0))=(0,0)$,
$$\begin{align*}f'((0,0),(\cos\theta,\sin\theta))&=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f((0,0)+t(\cos\theta,\sin\theta))-f(0,0)}{t}\\ &=\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{f((t\cos\theta,t\sin\theta))-(0,0)}{t} \end{align*}$$

I'm going to leave it there for a moment, because my question is how I'm going to continue evaluating a limit that has two components above, like $ (0,0) $, some help, because I don't understand how to continue. Or I will have to take the norm so that it gives me a value, and I can evaluate the limit. Thank you

Comment: No problem, because $f(t\cos\theta,t\sin\theta)$ also has two components. Undoubtedly somewhere near this point in your book there is an innocent looking result telling that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))=(\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f_1(x,y),\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f_2(x,y))$$ whenever the two limits on the right hand side both exist.

Comment: Yes, of course. I know that. But what can I do with the $ t $ that I have in the denominator? Can I put it in the components? To be able to assess the limit? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Are you sure about the definition of $f_2$? I ask this because, with this definition, $f$ isn't even continuous at $(0,0)$, and therefore it's not differentiable there.

Comment: In the book it appears $ L  (x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 + 1) $, and well I assume it is $ \ln $. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: If $(a,b)$ is some vector, surely
$$\frac1t(a,b)=(\frac at,\frac bt).$$
This is how you multiply a vector by a scalar, right? Here we divide by a non-zero scalar, but that is the same thing as multiplying by the reciprocal.